# garbage collect Stanford Maxent POS tagger

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I am using the Stanford Maxent POS tagger. Previously I had less amount of RAM allocated to the jar with the tagger instantiated within the program. However due to less memory, the tagger created 4 instances of itself which maxed out the heap.
Now I have allocated 1 GB ram to the jar and thankfully only one instance is created. I want to know if/how the tagger can be removed from memory after use, or is it Garbage-Collected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any way in which the tagger will create more instances of itself (except if you ask for multiple threads with the nthreads option). If you later set a MaxentTagger variable to null or similar, yes, it should be garbage collected.

Comment: You are right sir...I was  looking for a memory leak in the wrong direction. I had allocated 1024 MB  to the VM and still see a lot of  memory leaks in the jar. Had attributed to  the POS tagger. Need to look further.